# Pass multiple JSON objects to MVC5 action method

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass parameters array and string but don't send string parameter to control action. I use this code:

```
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Create(AddCategoryModel viewModel, string id) {}
```

I use this code  json  but don't pass `id` to action:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".btn-success").click(function(e)
            {   
                var formData = JSON.stringify($("#ajaxform").serializeArray());

               alert(formData);
               var MyForm = $("#ajaxform").serializeJSON();
               console.log(MyForm);
                $.ajax(
                {
                   url : "/Category/Create/", //,+ //$(foo).val(),   
                    //url: "Url.Action("Category", "Create", new { id = "oo"    })",
                    //id: $(foo).attr('value') ,
                    type: "POST",
                    data : {valArray:formData,'id':'20'},
                    success:function(maindta)
                    {

                        alert(maindta);

                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                    {
                    }
                });
                e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action

            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: So... You don't pass id to action... And then, what happens? Are you getting an error?

Comment: edit post:  i want to pass two  parameter  array and string.iam debug dont error .only dont get to controll